# probability of an event based on another event (Balls and dice problem)

Tags: probability

I have two bowls A and B.

Bowl **A** has **6 green** balls and **2 black** balls.

Bowl **B** has **4 green** balls and **3 black** balls.

We roll a **dice**, If the result is **1**. We pull a ball from Bowl **A**. Else we pull from **B**.

We repeat this experiment **100** times.

What is the probability of getting at least **1 Black** ball.

Is this correct?

$ p = 1-(1 - (\frac{1}{6}*\frac{2}{8} )+1-(\frac{5}{6}*\frac{3}{7}))^{100}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

The probability of "no black ball" for $1$ experiment is: $$P(E)=P(D=1)P(E\mid D=1)+P(D\neq1)P(E\mid D\neq1)=\frac16\times\frac68+\frac56\times\frac47$$(here $E$ denotes the event of "no black ball")

So the probability of "no black ball" for $100$ experiment is: $$\left(\frac16\times\frac68+\frac56\times\frac47\right)^{100}$$
Then the probability of "at least on black ball" for $100$ experiment is: $$1-\left(\frac16\times\frac68+\frac56\times\frac47\right)^{100}$$